# Insert specific elements in ASP:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, button, gridview

I have some problem with GridView component. My task is to insert into the gridview data from a class called a book whose number of pages is greater than 100. Class:

```
    public class Knjiga {
     public string nazivKnjige { get; set; }
     public string imeAutora { get; set; }
     public int brStr { get; set; }
     public int ID { get; set; }

     public Knjiga(string naziv, string ime, int broj, int id) {
       nazivKnjige = naziv;
       imeAutora = ime;
       brStr = broj;
       ID = id;
     }
  }
```

I try something like this:

```
     List<Knjiga> biblioteka = new List<Knjiga>() { 
       new Knjiga("Mali Princ", "Hans Kristiansen Andersen", 355, 009),
       new Knjiga("Na Drini cuprija", "Ivo Andric", 100, 088),
       new Knjiga("Starac i more", "Ernest Hemingvej", 67, 033),
       new Knjiga("Covek posle rata", "Dusan Vasiljev", 255, 011),
       new Knjiga("Gradinar", "Rabindranat Tagore", 125, 077)
     };

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < biblioteka.Count; i++)
    {
        if (biblioteka[i].brStr > 100)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = biblioteka;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < biblioteka.Count; i++)
    {
        if (biblioteka[i].brStr > 100)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = biblioteka;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I start a project, all the data is inserted into the gridview, regardless of whether its number of pages exceeds 100. Does anyone know how to insert only those objects where the number of pages is greater than 100 ??

Comment: Step through your code line by line. You'll notice that your setting the datasource and rebinding your gridview thousands of times, to the entire collection of objects in biblioteka. Instead, you need to create a smaller collection to bind to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Before binding the data, to grid view, prepare the data source based on your business.
2. You are binding the same data multiple times, as the data binding logic present in for-loop